# AtomのLaTeXにmendexを使わせるには？

Tags: atom-editor, latex

TeX Live 2018とAtomのLaTeXパッケージでupLaTeXを利用しています。
作成している文書に索引を付けるため、プリアンブルに
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
を、本文に\printindexを書いています。索引は作れるものの、日本語パートが一塊になってしまいます。つまり、「あ」で始まる単語と「い」で始まる単語の間に空行が入っていない状態です（英字パートは適切に空行が入っています）。

調べたところ、idxファイルからindファイルを作るのに、mendexではなくmakeindexが使われているのが原因らしいことが分かりました。実際、コマンドプロンプトでuplatex, mendex, uplatexの順に実行すると、望んだ出力が得られました。自分にできたのはここまでで、どうすればAtomでbuildする際にmendexを使うように設定できるかが分かりません。どうすればいいか教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。具体的には、[latex:latexmkの設定 [雑多な記録]](http://www2.yukawa.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekoudai.sugimoto/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=latex:latexmk%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)の方法を使ったところ上手くいきました。

Atomのlatexパッケージはlatexmkを利用しているので、latexパッケージの設定ではなくlatexmkの設定を変えます。そのために、C:User\Usernameの下に.latexmkrcという名称のファイルを作成し、そこに設定を書き込みます。今回はmakeindexをmendexに変えたかったので、

```
$makeindex = 'mendex -U %O -o %D %S';
```

とだけ書きました。